# Check box against dropdownlist item

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there anyway to create a `dropdownlist` or `combobox` with a check box on it. So the user can select multiple items at once.

The similar thing I found is the `checkedListBox`, but it grows when there are more items.

In my case I don't have enough space to use `checkedListBox`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

To have a combo/dropdown with checks is absolutely crazy idea because combo meant for selection of single item out of list.

If real estate is your problem you can create a hidden user control with listbox and OK button, make it popup when you click some button. For example, you can have a read-only text box with selected items listed semicolon-delimited with small `...` button next to it. When you click, list box pops up and you select stuff, close it, and it appears in your textbox.
This is just one of things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create your own control - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18929/An-OwnerDraw-ComboBox-with-CheckBoxes-in-the-Drop might be a good starting point.